# Excel Powerquery taking about 4 hours to refresh

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

I have written a series of PowerQueries that calculates an employees rolling 12 month sickness taking into account their shift pattern (may not be Mon-Fri) and their contracted hours.
It returns the number of days sick, the number of occurrences of sickness and the Bradford Score.
If someone is sick either side of a weekend it is counted as the same occurrence.

At the moment the raw data is contained in two CSV files at 180,908 records. It grows by about 3100 records per week - this represents the hours worked per employee per day.
The original data has 33 columns, but I only use 10.  The other columns are deleted as one of the first steps in the queries.

**The problem** is that I ran it and it took about four hours to update.... way too long.
Can anyone see any bottlenecks apart from the fact it's an Excel "database" so can't use any query folding.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

An example of the data is:
[image]

### Create some raw data:

- **A1**: `={"Date","Facility","Department","Status","Forename","Surname","Emp No","Contract","Sick","Wkg Patt"}`
- **A2**: `=SEQUENCE(438,,44296)` (format as date)
- **B2**: `=IF(A2#<>"",{"Warehouse","Inbound","Perm","D","BC","1",40})`
- **I2**: `=IF(MID(J2,WEEKDAY(A2,16),1)=0,"",IF(RANDBETWEEN(0,50)<10,RANDBETWEEN(1,8),""))`  - and fill down
- **J2**: `=IF(A2#<>"","0011111 " & REPT(CHAR(RANDBETWEEN(65,80)),RANDBETWEEN(0,5)))` - this represents the shift pattern with a series of 0's and 1's starting on a Saturday.  The text on the end shows this column wasn't originally intended for this, so may have other text in as well.

Save the data across two CSV files (I just changed "D", "BC" and "1" in the B2 formula before re-saving).

The Excel reporting file should also hold three tables (which can be left empty for the example).

- `Leavers` containing two columns (`Emp No` and `Name`)
- `NameUpdates` containing two columns (`Emp No` and `Name`)
- `IgnoreList` containing three columns (`Emp No`, `Start Date` and `End Date`).

There should also be two named cells - `StartDate` and `EndDate`.  These cells currently hold *17-Jun-22* and *18-Jun-21* respectively.

### The Queries:

**fnGetNamedRange**  - gets a value from a named range.  Used within **Raw Data** query.

```
let GetNamedRange=(NamedRange) => 
    let
        name = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=NamedRange]}[Content],
        value = name{0}[Column1]
    in
        value
in GetNamedRange
```

**Raw Data**
This query combines the two CSV files, removes any leavers listed in the `Leavers` table, updates any mis-spelled names in the `NameUpdates` table and filters the table to the required dates.

```
let
    //Import data from the Reporting Suite.
    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(
        "C:\Documents\Raw Data Suite.csv"
        ),[Delimiter=",", Columns=33, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    RemoveTopRows = Table.Skip(Source,0), //Normally 3, set to 0 for example.
    ReportingSuitePromoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(RemoveTopRows, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    ReportingSuiteRemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(ReportingSuitePromoteHeaders,{"Date", "Facility", "Status", "Forename", "Surname", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department", "Sick", "Wkg Patt"}),

    //Import data from the Archive.
    ArchiveSource = Csv.Document(File.Contents(
        "C:\Documents\Archive.csv"
        ),[Delimiter=",", Columns=33, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None]),
    ArchivePromoteHeaders = Table.PromoteHeaders(ArchiveSource, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    ArchiveRemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(ArchivePromoteHeaders,{"Date", "Facility", "Status", "Forename", "Surname", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department", "Sick", "Wkg Patt"}),

    //Combine the two tables of data.
    CombineTables = Table.Combine({ReportingSuiteRemoveOtherColumns, ArchiveRemoveOtherColumns}),

    //Join Forename & Surname.
    TrimNames = Table.TransformColumns(CombineTables,{{"Forename", Text.Trim, type text}, {"Surname", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    JoinEmployeeName = Table.CombineColumns(TrimNames,{"Forename", "Surname"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(" ", QuoteStyle.None),"Name"),
    ChangeNameCase = Table.TransformColumns(JoinEmployeeName,{{"Name", Text.Proper, type text}}),

    //Reference Name Updates table.
    NameSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameUpdates"]}[Content],
    ChangeDataType1 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(NameSource,{{"Emp No", type text}, {"Name", type text}}),
    MergeTables = Table.NestedJoin(ChangeNameCase, {"Emp No"}, ChangeDataType1, {"Emp No"}, "NameUpdates", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandNameUpdates = Table.ExpandTableColumn(MergeTables, "NameUpdates", {"Name"}, {"NameUpdates.Name"}),
    AddNewNameColumn = Table.AddColumn(ExpandNameUpdates, "New Name", each if [NameUpdates.Name] = null then [Name] else [NameUpdates.Name], type text),

    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(AddNewNameColumn,{"Date", "Facility", "Status", "New Name", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department", "Sick", "Wkg Patt"}),
    RenameColumn = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns,{{"New Name", "Name"}}),
    ChangeDataType2 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RenameColumn,
        {{"Date", type date}, {"Facility", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Name", type text}, {"Emp No", type text}, {"Contract", type number}, {"Department", type text}, {"Sick", type number}, {"Wkg Patt", type text}}),

    //Filter to required dates and select Perm employees who have had a period of sick.
    FilterDates = Table.SelectRows(ChangeDataType2, each [Date] >= Date.From(fnGetNamedRange("StartDate")) and [Date] <= Date.From(fnGetNamedRange("EndDate"))),
    FilterRows = Table.SelectRows(FilterDates, each ([Status] = "Perm")),

    //Reference the Leavers table.
    LeaversSource = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Leavers"]}[Content],
    RemovedName = Table.SelectColumns(LeaversSource,{"Emp No"}),
    ChangeDataType3 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(RemovedName,{{"Emp No", type text}}),
    RemoveLeavers = Table.NestedJoin(FilterRows, {"Emp No"}, ChangeDataType3, {"Emp No"}, "Leavers", JoinKind.LeftAnti),
    RemoveLeaverColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(RemoveLeavers,{"Leavers"}),
    SortTable = Table.Sort(RemoveLeaverColumn,{{"Emp No", Order.Ascending}, {"Date", Order.Ascending}}),

    //Indicate which days are work days and which aren't.
    GetShiftPattern = Table.AddColumn(SortTable, "Shift Pattern", each Text.Start(Text.From([Wkg Patt], "en-GB"), 7), type text),
    IsShiftPattern = Table.AddColumn(GetShiftPattern, "ShiftPatternCheck", each Value.Is(Value.FromText(Text.Start(Text.From([Wkg Patt], "en-GB"), 7)), type number)),
    IsWorkDay = Table.AddColumn(IsShiftPattern, "WorkDay", each if [ShiftPatternCheck]=true then Text.Middle([Shift Pattern], Date.DayOfWeek([Date], Day.Saturday), 1) else 
                                                                if Date.DayOfWeek([Date],Day.Saturday)<=1 then 0 else 1, type text),
    ChangeDataType4 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(IsWorkDay,{{"WorkDay", Int64.Type}}),
    RemoveShiftPatternColumns = Table.Buffer(Table.RemoveColumns(ChangeDataType4,{"Wkg Patt", "Shift Pattern", "ShiftPatternCheck"})),

    //Combine Departments
    RemoveOtherColumns1 = Table.SelectColumns(RemoveShiftPatternColumns,{"Emp No", "Department"}),
    RemoveDuplicates1 = Table.Distinct(RemoveOtherColumns1),
    GroupDepartments = Table.Group(RemoveDuplicates1, {"Emp No"}, {{"Department", each Text.Combine([Department], ", "), type nullable text}}),
    AddDepartments = Table.NestedJoin(RemoveShiftPatternColumns, {"Emp No"}, GroupDepartments, {"Emp No"}, "Dept", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    ExpandDepartments = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddDepartments, "Dept", {"Department"}, {"Department.1"}),
    RemoveOtherColumns2 = Table.SelectColumns(ExpandDepartments,{"Date", "Facility", "Status", "Name", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department.1", "Sick", "WorkDay"}),
    RenameColumns = Table.Buffer(Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns2,{{"Department.1", "Department"}}))
    
in
    RenameColumns
```

**Non-work days** - lists each employees off days based on the 0's and 1's in the Wkg Patt column.

```
let
    Source = #"Raw Data",
    RemoveWorkingDays = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([WorkDay] = 0)),
    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.Buffer(Table.SelectColumns(RemoveWorkingDays,{"Date", "Emp No"}))
in
    RemoveOtherColumns
```

**fnNetworkDays** - calculates number of working days excluding Holidays (or off-days in this case)

```
let 
    func = (StartDate as date, EndDate as date, optional Holidays as list, optional StartOfWeek as number) =>
        let 
            // optional StartOfWeek, if empty the week will start on Monday
            startOfWeek = if StartOfWeek = null then 1 else StartOfWeek,

            // Providing for logic where EndDate is after StartDate
            Start = List.Min({StartDate, EndDate}),
            End = List.Max({StartDate, EndDate}),
            
            // Switch sign if EndDate is before StartDate
            Sign = if EndDate < StartDate then -1 else 1,
            
            // Get list of dates between Start- and EndDate
            ListOfDates = List.Dates(Start, Number.From(End-Start)+1,#duration(1,0,0,0)),


            // if the optional Holidays parameter is used: Keep only those dates in the list that don't occur in the list of Holidays;
            // otherwise continue with previous table
            DeleteHolidays = if Holidays = null then ListOfDates else List.Difference(ListOfDates, List.Transform(Holidays, Date.From )),

            // Count the number of days (items in the list)
            CountDays = List.Count(DeleteHolidays) * Sign
        in 
            CountDays
in 
    func
```

**fnNONWORKDAYS**  - returns the dates that an employee isn't working based on the `Non-work days` query.

```
let 
    non_work_dates = (SourceTable as table, StartDate as date, EndDate as date, EmpNo as text) =>
        let 
            Source = SourceTable,
            FilterToEmpNo = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Emp No] = EmpNo and [Date] >= StartDate and [Date] <= EndDate),
            RemoveEmpNo = Table.SelectColumns(FilterToEmpNo,{"Date"}),
            ToList = RemoveEmpNo[Date]
        in 
            ToList
in
    non_work_dates
```

**Periods of Sick** - identifies the start and end dates of each period of sickness

```
let
    Source = #"Raw Data",
    FilterToSick = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Sick] <> null)),

    //The data is sorted by Employee Number and Date so periods of sickness per employee appear next to each other.
    //Add three indexes so data from the previous and next row may be referenced in the current row.
    //Index1 starts at 1.  
    AddIndex1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(FilterToSick, "Index1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    Index1PK = Table.AddKey(AddIndex1, {"Index1"}, true),
    SortByIndex1 = Table.Sort(Index1PK, {"Index1", Order.Ascending}),

    //We're only adding the Date & Emp No from the previous & next row to the current row.
    //So a table is created containing only those two fields.
    //Add Index2 to the JoinTable.  This will start at 0
    JoinTable = Table.SelectColumns(Index1PK,{"Date", "Emp No"}),
    AddIndex2 = Table.AddIndexColumn(JoinTable, "Index2", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    Index2PK = Table.AddKey(AddIndex2, {"Index2"}, true),
    SortByIndex2PK = Table.Sort(Index2PK, {"Index2", Order.Ascending}),

    //Add Index3 to the JoinTable.  This will start at 2
    AddIndex3 = Table.AddIndexColumn(JoinTable, "Index3", -1, 1, Int64.Type),
    Index3PK = Table.AddKey(AddIndex3, {"Index3"}, true),
    SortByIndex3PK = Table.Sort(Index3PK, {"Index3", Order.Ascending}),

    //Add the Employee Number and Date from the next row to the current row.
    Index2Merge = Table.Join(Table.PrefixColumns(SortByIndex2PK, "Prev"), {"Prev.Index2"}, Table.PrefixColumns(SortByIndex1,"Current"), {"Current.Index1"}, JoinAlgorithm.SortMerge),
    SortByDate1 = Table.Sort(Index2Merge,{{"Current.Emp No", Order.Ascending}, {"Current.Date", Order.Ascending}}),

    Index3Merge = Table.Join(Table.PrefixColumns(SortByIndex3PK,"Next"), {"Next.Index3"}, SortByDate1,  {"Current.Index1"}, JoinAlgorithm.SortMerge),
    SortByDate1Again = Table.Sort(Index3Merge,{{"Current.Emp No", Order.Ascending}, {"Current.Date", Order.Ascending}}),

    DaysSincePreviousSick = Table.AddColumn(SortByDate1Again, "Days Since Previous", each try fnNetworkDays([Prev.Date],[Current.Date],fnNONWORKDAYS(#"Non-work days",[Prev.Date], [Current.Date], [Current.Emp No]))-1 otherwise null),
    DaysToNextSick = Table.AddColumn(DaysSincePreviousSick, "Days To Next", each try fnNetworkDays([Current.Date],[Next.Date],fnNONWORKDAYS(#"Non-work days",[Current.Date], [Next.Date], [Current.Emp No]))-1 otherwise null),

    IdentifyStart = Table.AddColumn(DaysToNextSick, "Start", each if [Days Since Previous]<>1 or [Prev.Date]=null or [Current.Emp No]<>[Prev.Emp No] then "Start" else null),
    IdentifyEnd = Table.AddColumn(IdentifyStart, "End", each if [Days To Next]<>1 or [Current.Emp No]<>[Next.Emp No] then "End" else null),
    RemoveOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns(IdentifyEnd,{"Current.Date", "Current.Facility", "Current.Status", "Current.Name", "Current.Emp No", "Current.Contract", "Current.Department", "Current.Sick", "Start", "End"}),
    RenameColumns= Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns,{{"Current.Date", "Date"}, {"Current.Facility", "Facility"}, {"Current.Status", "Status"}, {"Current.Name", "Name"}, 
                                                           {"Current.Emp No", "Emp No"}, {"Current.Contract", "Contract"}, {"Current.Department", "Department"}, {"Current.Sick", "Sick"}})
in 
    RenameColumns
```

**fnSumBetween**  - sums the sick hours between two dates for a specified employee number.

```
let
    Sum_Between = (SourceTable as table, StartDate as date, EndDate as date, EmpNo as text) =>
        let  
            Source = SourceTable,
            FilterToData = Table.SelectRows(Source, each [Emp No] = EmpNo and [Date] >= StartDate and [Date] <= EndDate),
            GroupRows = Table.Group(FilterToData, {"Emp No"}, {{"Sick Hours", each List.Sum([Sick]), type nullable number}})
        in  
            GroupRows
in
    Sum_Between
```

**Total Periods of Sick**  - returns a single row for each sickness period along with number of days sick.

```
let
    Source = #"Periods of Sick",
    MergeStartAndEnd = Table.CombineColumns(Source,{"Start", "End"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"SickPeriods"),
    
    //Add multi-day sick.
    FilterRows1 = Table.SelectRows(MergeStartAndEnd, each ([SickPeriods] = "End" or [SickPeriods] = "Start")),
    AddIndex1 = Table.AddIndexColumn(FilterRows1, "Index1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    AddIndex2 = Table.AddIndexColumn(AddIndex1, "Index2", 1, 1, Int64.Type),

    MergeIndexes = Table.Join(AddIndex2, "Index1", Table.PrefixColumns(AddIndex2,"1"), "1.Index2", JoinAlgorithm.SortMerge),
    FilterRows2 = Table.SelectRows(MergeIndexes, each ([SickPeriods] = "End")),
    RemoveOtherColumns1 = Table.SelectColumns(FilterRows2,
            {"1.Date", "Date", "Facility", "Status", "Name", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department"}),
    RenameColumns1 = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns1,{{"1.Date", "From"}, {"Date", "To"}}),

    AddSickHours = Table.AddColumn(RenameColumns1, "Sick", each fnSumBetween(#"Periods of Sick",[From],[To],[Emp No])),
    ExpandTable = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddSickHours, "Sick", {"Sick Hours"}, {"Sick Hours"}),

    //Add single day sick periods.
    FilterRows3 = Table.SelectRows(MergeStartAndEnd, each ([SickPeriods] = "StartEnd")),
    DuplicateDateColumn = Table.DuplicateColumn(FilterRows3, "Date", "To"),
    RemoveOtherColumns2 = Table.SelectColumns(DuplicateDateColumn,{"Date", "To", "Facility", "Status", "Name", "Emp No", "Contract", "Department", "Sick"}),
    RenameColumns2 = Table.RenameColumns(RemoveOtherColumns2,{{"Date", "From"}, {"Sick", "Sick Hours"}}),
    
    //Join single and multi day sick periods.
    AppendData = Table.Combine({ExpandTable, RenameColumns2}),
    SortRows = Table.Sort(AppendData,{{"Emp No", Order.Ascending}, {"From", Order.Ascending}}),
    CalculateDaysSick = Table.AddColumn(SortRows, "Days Sick", each Number.Round([Sick Hours]/([Contract]/5),2))
in
    CalculateDaysSick
```

**Bradford Score**  - returns total number of days and occurrences of sickness along with the [Bradford Score](https://www.bradfordfactorcalculator.com/)

```
let
    Source = #"Total Periods of Sick",
    GroupRows = Table.Group(Source, {"Emp No", "Name", "Department", "Facility"}, {{"Total Days", each List.Sum([Days Sick]), type number}, {"Occurrences", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}}),
    AddBradfordScore = Table.AddColumn(GroupRows, "Bradford Score", each Number.Power([Occurrences],2)*[Total Days])
in
    AddBradfordScore
```

Comment: You really should be using a database product for such volumes.

Comment: I'm not even going to try to comb through all your code. I would use `/*` and `*/` to comment out sections of your code and run it to see if you can pinpoint where the bottleneck is. Not sure if you are reprocessing the 180K "historical" rows every time, or if you can just process the new rows only.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tool, as if trying to use a goldsmith's hammer to drive a railroad spike. There are *many* relational databases available, including free [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) *Base*, and [many others](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/free-database-software/).  For *Base*, and many other databases, the [CSV files can be imported into a new database](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/import-csv-data-into-database/43435/2) with little effort.

It might take a short while to [learn the basics of a database query language](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/sql-tutorial/), such as a version of SQL, but it will make your task *far simpler* and more achievable.

Comment: Thank you.  I knew I was reaching the limit of Excel - just wasn't sure how powerful PowerQuery could be.  Gives me a bit of ammunition to go back to the bosses and push through the database solution - already have the design planned out, can import the data and breakdown to 3NF (I think - been a while). Might build the back-end anyway so I can get these reports done in a sensible time.  Guess I should delete the question as not the right tool?

Comment: Actually, the question *is* reasonable, as you state, to provide data for you to take to a decision maker. You can show the situation as it it now, with updates taking four hours, and show recommendations from others that there are solutions, whether through a commercial product such as Oracle, or a free database such as LibreOffice Base. You might suggest starting a Base project to run in parallel with the current Excel spreadsheet... no cost in software, but you or other developers would need time to create and test it.